# Merge sort join in R

Tags: r, sorting, join

I was wondering if R supports joining on sorted keys ? The idea is to speed up merging two dataframes with sorted keys (in occurence, a date column). I'm currently using dplyr's `inner_join` function.

Comment: data.table::merge will be faster, but I don't know much about its implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want keys, you should have a look at `data.table`. You can set a primary key using

```r
data.table::setkev(df1, c("col1","col2"))
```

Setting a key will reorder your dataframe in contiguous memory slots. This will speed up a lot computations, in particular join, thanks to the binary search.

To merge datasets with keys, you will use `merge` function. By default, it will join on keys if they are set.

You can have look at [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html) on the subject